# Play JSON Writes how it gets field values into correct field

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I was trying to understand Writes[T] at a deeper level than just accepting it works which I know it does. What I am confused about is after unapplying and lifting T my understanding is you end of with a tuple of values. How does it match these values to the proper place if they are all the same type for instance Doubles as below? I wondered if it had to do with order of combinators but local experimentation seems to show me order is not important.  Example from ScalaJsonCombinators page of Play Docs:

```
case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
 (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double] and
 (JsPath \ "long").write[Double]
)(unlift(Location.unapply))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It absolutely has to do with the order of the combinators vs the order of fields in `Location.unapply`, otherwise there would be no deterministic way to write `Reads` and `Writes`.

```
implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double] and
  (JsPath \ "long").write[Double]
)(unlift(Location.unapply))

scala> Json.stringify(Json.toJson(Location(2.11, 42.12)))
res2: String = {"lat":2.11,"long":42.12}
```

The path names in `Writes` are irrelevant to the field names of `Location`, it just applies them in order:

```
// Reversed
implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "long").write[Double] and
  (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double]
)(unlift(Location.unapply))

scala> Json.stringify(Json.toJson(Location(2.11, 42.12)))
res3: String = {"long":2.11,"lat":42.12}
```